# Spring fetch public key from authentication service via Eureka

Tags: spring, spring-security, netflix-eureka

I'm implementing a Spring Security Resource Server that validating JWT tokens with a public key.
I'm trying to fetch the public key from the Authentication Service I've built, via Eureka service.
The fetching occurring on service startup, before the service registers on Eureka.
So when it's calling the authentication service, an UnknownHostException is thrown.
Can I modify the order and set the key just after Eureka registration finished?

```
@EnableResourceServer
public class MyResourceServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        HttpEntity<Void> request = new HttpEntity<Void>(new HttpHeaders());
        ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(AUTH_URI, HttpMethod.GET, request, Map.class);
        String publicKey = (String) responseEntity.getBody().get("value");            
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);

        return converter;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should remove jwt from tags.You problem wouldn't have changed much if you had used simple tokens. Also remove service-discovery. Question is specific to eureka, not all service-discovery frameworks.

Comment: I removed it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`@DependsOn`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) annotation can help.

From docs:

> ... Used infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization. ...

You can try adding `@Depends("discoveryClient")` to the class implementing auth-service client.

Note: I haven't tested if the bean name should be `discoveryClient`. Please see debug logs to see correct bean name if this doesn't work.